# Xml декодирование Golang

Tags: xml, golang

Тренируюсь с декодированием xml и возникла проблема. Почему-то при декодировке функция Unmarshal декодирует только первый элемент структуры. Все остальные - игнорируюстся, хотя прочитаны в переменной byteValue.
Имеется XML -сттсруктура

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Person id="13">
  <name>
   <first>Abigail</first>
   <last>Moriarti</last>
  </name>
 </Person> <Person id="15">
  <name>
   <first>James</first>
   <last>Willow</last>
  </name>
 </Person> <Person id="16">
  <name>
   <first>Margareth</first>
   <last>O"Nil</last>
  </name>
 </Person> <Person id="17">
  <name>
   <first>Lowan</first>
   <last>de Vega</last>
  </name>
 </Person>
```

Мой код для дешифровки:

```
type Person struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml: "person"`
    Id        int      `xml:"id,attr"`
    FirstName string   `xml:"name>first"`
    LastName  string   `xml:"name>last"`
}

func FullDecode() {
    xmlFile, err := os.Open("EncodeData.xml")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Successfully Opened EncodeData.xml")
    defer xmlFile.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
    var persons []Person
    err = xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &persons)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Cannot Decode xml")
    }
    Writefile, err := os.Create("DecodeData.txt")

    for _, person := range persons {
        finastring := string(person.Id) + " " + person.FirstName + " " + person.LastName
        Writefile.WriteString(finastring)
    }
}
```

Значение которое получается в результате:

```
1.
2. Abigail Moriarti
```

Почему в данном примере Unmarshal не декодирует весь файл, а останавливается на первом элементе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В XML документе на верхнем уровне должен быть ровно один элемент. Если таких элементов больше одного, то это некорректный XML документ.

Вам нужно обернуть список персон в какой-то тег. Например, `<persons></persons>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persons>
    <person id="13">
        <name>
            <first>Abigail</first>
            <last>Moriarti</last>
        </name>
    </person>
    <person id="15">
        <name>
            <first>James</first>
            <last>Willow</last>
        </name>
    </person>
    <person id="16">
        <name>
            <first>Margareth</first>
            <last>O"Nil</last>
        </name>
    </person>
    <person id="17">
        <name>
            <first>Lowan</first>
            <last>de Vega</last>
        </name>
    </person>
</persons>
```

Вот пример кода, который успешно парсит такой XML. Обратите внимание на `Persons []Person` в структуре `Persons` - именно этот массив указывает парсеру, что элементов `person` может быть более одного.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func parseXMLFile[T any](fileName string, dst *T) error {
    bytes, err := os.ReadFile(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return xml.Unmarshal(bytes, dst)
}

type Person struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"person"`
    Id        int      `xml:"id,attr"`
    FirstName string   `xml:"name>first"`
    LastName  string   `xml:"name>last"`
}

type Persons struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"persons"`
    Persons []Person `xml:"person"`
}

func main() {
    var persons Persons

    if err := parseXMLFile("persons.xml", &persons); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Persons: %v\n", persons.Persons)
}
```

**UPDATE**

если же вам нужно парсить некорректный XML файл, то это можно сделать при помощи потокового декодера [`xml.Decoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Decoder)

Некорректный файл `persons2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <person id="13">
        <name>
            <first>Abigail</first>
            <last>Moriarti</last>
        </name>
    </person>
    <person id="15">
        <name>
            <first>James</first>
            <last>Willow</last>
        </name>
    </person>
    <person id="16">
        <name>
            <first>Margareth</first>
            <last>O"Nil</last>
        </name>
    </person>
    <person id="17">
        <name>
            <first>Lowan</first>
            <last>de Vega</last>
        </name>
    </person>
```

Как его парсить:

```
func main() {
    bz, err := os.ReadFile("persons2.xml")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    r := bytes.NewReader(bz)
    d := xml.NewDecoder(r)

    var person Person
    for d.Decode(&person) == nil {
        fmt.Printf("Person: %v\n", person)
    }
}
```

В цикле вызываете `d.Decode` до тех пор, пока вызов не вернёт ошибку.
Результат (https://go.dev/play/p/qfMb1kclPSi):

```
Person: {{ person} 13 Abigail Moriarti}
Person: {{ person} 15 James Willow}
Person: {{ person} 16 Margareth O"Nil}
Person: {{ person} 17 Lowan de Vega}
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду теперь разбираться как внести данные под дополнительную структуру

Comment: @arrr добавил потоковый парсер, подходит для разбора некорректных XML документов